# laravel UserRequest $request error

Tags: laravel, request

laravel5.2,I create a UserRequest.php under Requests directory,but in controller,`public function add(UserRequest $request)` show error,but use `public function add(Request $request)` is normal.

**UserRequest**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request
{
    /** 
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request. 
     * 
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_sn'   => 'required|unique',
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|unique',
            'password'  => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function add(UserRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->get('dosubmit')) {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $request
                ->rules(), $request->messages());
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect('user/add')->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
            }
        }
        $corporation_list = DB::table('corporation')->get();
        $department_list = DB::table('department')->get();

        return view('user.add', ['corporation_list' => $corporation_list, 'department_list' => $department_list]);
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware'],function (){
Route::any('user/add',['as'=>'user.add','uses'=>'UserController@add']);
```

});

Comment: You need to add `use` statement at top of file for `UserRequest`! Like: `use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;`

Comment: Is you `add()` method use to show the form or process the form submission or both?

Comment: yes ,both ,is the problem here?

Comment: Yes. If you can add the `Route`s and the `add()` method to your question as well I'll be able to help you out.

Comment: Route::any('user/add',['as'=>'user.add','uses'=>'UserController@add'])

Comment: Can you add the `add()` method from your controller as well? If you click the `edit` link above the comments you can add it to your question.

Comment: I have added it to my question

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually 2 reasons you could be having this issue.

1. You've not added the `use` statement for the `UserRequest`.

   At the top of your controller (above the `class`) add:

   ```
   use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest
   ```

   assuming that is the correct namespace.
2. You may need to run `composer dump-autoload` to make sure the class has been added to the autoloader.

---

### Edit

Firstly, replace the `add()` method with the following methods:

```
public function create()
{
    $corporation_list = DB::table('corporation')->get();
    $department_list = DB::table('department')->get();

    return view('user.add', compact('corporation_list', 'department_list'));
}

public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    // If you get to this point the validation will have passed

    // Process the request
}
```

Then change your routes from:

```
Route::any('user/add',['as'=>'user.add','uses'=>'UserControl‌​ler@add'])
```

to:

```
Route::get('user/add', ['as' => 'user.add', 'uses' => 'UserControl‌​ler@create']);
Route::post('user/add', ['as' => 'user.store', 'uses' => 'UserControl‌​ler@store']);
```

Obviously, feel free to change the `as` in the Routes to whatever, they should unique though.

Lastly, I would suggest looking at [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers) which is a RESTful approach.

Comment: your issue1 I have already use this statement,so I tried issue 2,but problem is still,this problem appears when I use iframe in my project ,when I click the left menu,the right show the "welcome page" not the correct page.but when  I use Request $request,the right show the right page

Comment: @zahdxj Would you be able to add the code for the `UserRequest` to your question?

Comment: I have posted my UserRequest

Comment: how can I do it? I'm a newer to stackoverflow

Comment: @zahdxj Glad I could help! Lastly, you might find this series useful https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not identified **UserController** that you are using **UserRequest** file

```
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest
```

It will solve the problem